# Political Topic all (most) students would agree on

Tags: teaching

For a class demonstration, I am seeking a political topic that all of my students (US undergraduate class) would pretty much hold the same opinion on. The original topic from the research I'm basing the demo on was support for the Castro regime in Cuba (study was conducted in the 1960s) - everyone was against it. I have used support for ISIS (ISIL) in the past (again, everyone against it), but I have often had to explain who ISIS was to students. I'm teaching asynchronously this semester, so won't have the opportunity to do that.

I would greatly appreciate ideas.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni this may be lost in translation. The original post does not imply that all students would agree _to_ support ISIS. They would agree _on_ support for ISIS, namely that such support would be a bad thing.

Comment: The book *How To* by Randall Munroe (best known as the author of the webcomic xkcd) has a list in Chapter 24 of the most popular opinions.  E.g. 98% of Americans would like to see a decline in high unemployment.

Comment: Vote for women?

Comment: democracy (however defined) is better than fascism (however defined)?  mixed-race marriage? (only 91% think "good for society" or "not much difference" as of a 2017 survey ... https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2017/05/18/2-public-views-on-intermarriage/, but 95% for ages 18-29)

Comment: [We should not systematically euthanize everyone at the age of 30.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film))

Comment: @JeffE but at 60 it’s fine...

Answer (score 2):

Poverty is bad.

Polluting the environment is bad.

Murdering people because of their race or religion is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the boundary between "political" and "societal" is, nor what your cutoff for "most" is, but: as of 2017, 91% of a sample of the US population thought interracial marriage was either "good for society" or "not much difference" as opposed to "bad for society"; 96% of the 18-29 age group thought so ([Pew Social Trends](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2017/05/18/2-public-views-on-intermarriage/)). (There must be a bit of rounding error, as "bad for society" is listed as 5% in the same line ...)

[image]